# How to get the value of transaction per second in graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to know my transaction per second using graph in jmeter here's my graph:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Transactions Per Second support [Aggregated display](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=TransactionsPerSecond#Aggregated-display) you can click Settings and check the option Aggregated display, see screenshoot:
[image]